# Deadlock between two non-related tables

Tags: deadlock

Sometimes happens deadlock on 2 tables, but I dont see any relation between them.

They have the same column name that called 'Code' but there is no relation between these 2 columns.
No triggers on table.
The lock is on indexes UIXC_Stats and PK_Rates.

UIXC_Stats its unique clusterd index at table Test.dbo.Stats that includes several column sincluding also column Code that exist at both tables.
PK_Rates its clustered primary key that includes 2 columns at table Test.dbo.Rates , one of them is Code column.

This is the deadlock schema:

```
 <deadlock><victim-list><victimProcess id="process1c48ce29468" /></victim-list>
<process-list><process id="process1c48ce29468" taskpriority="0" logused="2628" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057595777318912 
(a48b1d843aaa)" waittime="4028" ownerId="67284120064" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2023-09-19T05:00:03.417" XDES="0x1c56475c460" lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="2"
 kpid="12224" status="suspended" spid="173" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-09-19T05:00:03.417" lastbatchcompleted="2023-09-19T05:00:03.417" 
 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.417" clientapp="Node1" hostname="NG-LOT-B1" hostpid="6315" loginname="NEO\CGS_Backend_UI" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="67284120064" 
 currentdb="7" currentdbname="Test" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056"><executionStack><frame procname="Test.dbo.procRatesSet" 
 line="157" stmtstart="10644" stmtend="11418" sqlhandle="0x0300070094bb7a6b44b071006cb0000001000000000000000">
UPDATE  cr 
    SET     Rate            = new.Rate, 
            OperatorID      = new.OperatorID, 
            LastUpdateDate  = new.LastUpdateDate
    FROM    dbo.Rates AS cr
            INNER JOIN (    SELECT  RateDay, Code, Rate, OperatorID, LastUpdateDate
                            FROM    @ToUpdate AS cr 
                                    CROSS JOIN @DaysToUpdate AS d
                        ) AS new ON cr.RateDay = new.RateDay AND cr.Code = new.Code    </frame></executionStack><inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1803205524]   </inputbuf></process>




<process id="process1c48ce3dc28" taskpriority="0" logused="24108" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057595988475904 (71ffa95c3f24)"
 waittime="4023" ownerId="67284113571" transactionname="MERGE" lasttranstarted="2023-09-19T05:00:02.947" XDES="0x1c55bbf8460" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4"
 kpid="12240" status="suspended" spid="124" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-09-19T05:00:02.700" lastbatchcompleted="2023-09-19T05:00:02.700"
 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.700" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x277A6ABC1DF7 : Step 3)" hostname="NG-LOT-S1" hostpid="1235" loginname="NEO\sqlservice"
 isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="67284113571" currentdb="7" currentdbname="Test" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056"><executionStack>
 <frame procname="Test.dbo.procStatsMerge" line="47" stmtstart="2846" stmtend="16400" sqlhandle="0x0300070078a7821287967e0062af">

WITH DailyStatisticsSource AS
    (
        SELECT  ID,Reference,Code,Total    </frame><frame procname="adhoc" line="3" stmtstart="114" stmtend="326" 
sqlhandle="0x0100080016aa6109a04b4292c501">
EXEC Test.dbo.procStatsMerge @ErrorCode=@ErrorCode1 OUTPUT,@ErrorMessage=@ErrorMessage1 OUTPU    </frame></executionStack><inputbuf>

DECLARE @ErrorCode1 int, @ErrorMessage1 varchar(4000)
EXEC Test.dbo.procStatsMerge @ErrorCode=@ErrorCode1 OUTPUT,@ErrorMessage=@ErrorMessage1 OUTPUT
SELECT @ErrorCode1, @ErrorMessage1
   </inputbuf></process></process-list><resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057595777318912" dbid="7" objectname="Test.dbo.Stats" indexname="UIXC_Stats" 
   id="lock1c58b047b00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057595777318912"><owner-list><owner id="process1c48ce3dc28" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
   <waiter id="process1c48ce29468" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait" /></waiter-list></keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057595988475904" dbid="7" objectname="Test.dbo.Rates" indexname="PK_Rates" id="lock1c9387c0280" mode="X"
   associatedObjectId="72057595988475904"><owner-list><owner id="process1c48ce29468" mode="X" />
   </owner-list><waiter-list><waiter id="process1c48ce3dc28" mode="S" requestType="wait" /></waiter-list></keylock></resource-list>   
   </deadlock>
```

Comment: A relationship between two tables is not required for concurrency issues to occur. Concurrency issues arise from the manner and degree of usage between resources or tables. Two processes 173 and 124 got sandwiched, and in order to avoid a deadlock sql server rolled back the command with the least number of resources. The victim is almost always a SELECT statement.  What does the stored procedure procStatsMerge do, and could you see where contention issues could arise if that proc is called many times concurrently?

Comment: Also, what does "@ToUpdate" contain? It appears that is the data being written to. Can you see any intersections between the data in @ToUpdate and what is going on in procStatsMerge?

Comment: DECLARE @ToUpdate TABLE 
(
 Code CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 Rate   NUMERIC(9,7),
 LastUpdateDate SMALLDATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)

Comment: Sorry, still not clear how update of table Rates can affect merge on table Stats

Comment: What I can see if that the lockresource is of the type key. It is possible to figure out which table, key, and even row this is pointing to. Read this website, which has a step by step guide on how to figure it out (under the header keylock waits: https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/17/decoding-key-and-page-waitresource-for-deadlocks-and-blocking/